# Format number values in kendo grid fields to decimal problems

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I need to display numbers in my kendoGrid in decimal(2) format. But nothing seems to work so far. So I need help understanding why. I searched forums but the simple
'set type field to number and use format:"{0:n2}"' doesnt work. Im getting my data from a JSON where there are many decimals for a field value. So I want them to be only 2 decimals in my kendoGrid.

here is my code and my failed tries to get it work

```
var gridStavke = $("#gridItems").kendoGrid({
         scrollable: true,
         sortable: true,
         resizable: true,
         dataSource: {
          schema: {
            model: {

                fields: {

                    PDV25 : { type : "number" },
                    PDV3 : { type : "number" },
                    PDV28 : { type : "number" }
                }
            }
        }
    },
        height: $(document).height() - 190,          
        columns: [
            {field: "product", title: "Product"},
            {field: "price", title: "Price"},
            {field: "base", title: "Base"},
            {field: "count", title: "Count",footerTemplate:"total"},
            {field: "PDV25", title: "PDV 25%",format:"{0:n2}"},
            {field:"PDV3",title:"PDV 3%",format:"{0:n2}", editor:function(container,options){$('<input />').appendTo(container).kendoNumericTextBox({format:"n",decimals:2});}},
            {field: "PDV28", title: "PDV 28%", editor:numberEditor}

        ]

    }).data("kendoGrid");
    function numberEditor(container, options) {
$('<input name="' + options.field + '"/>')
        .appendTo(container)
        .kendoNumericTextBox({
            format  : "{0:n2}",
            decimals: 2,
            step    : 0.01
        });
}
```

JSON

```
"data":[
    {
        "product":"Med",
        "price":"40.3",
        "count":"1",
        "base":"238.42628640776698",
        "PDV25":"8.059999999999999",
        "PDV28":"54.68750000000001",
        "PDV3":"0.32621359223300966"
    },
    {
        "product":"Sir",
        "price":"250",
        "count":"1",
        "base":"238.42628640776698",
        "PDV25":"8.059999999999999",
        "PDV28":"54.68750000000001",
        "PDV3":"0.32621359223300966"
    },
    {
        "product":"Mlijeko",
        "price":"11.2",
        "count":"2",
        "base":"238.42628640776698",
        "PDV25":"8.059999999999999",
        "PDV28":"54.68750000000001",
        "PDV3":"0.32621359223300966"
    }
]
```

EDIT: I found the solution of the problem. I need to add template: '#= parseFloat(namefield).toFixed(2)#' in the {field...} parameters.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this problem because you are not setting right json data source. In Json value in double quotes ("") represent a string not a number, 
Number should be without quotes("").  That's why number format not applied to it. So Change your json and it will work.

A valid json should be like this :

```
 "data":[
        {
            "product":"Med",
            "price":40.3,
            "count":"1",
            "base":238.42628640776698,
            "PDV25":8.059999999999999,
            "PDV28":54.68750000000001,
            "PDV3":0.32621359223300966
        },..
]
```

Comment: i used parseFloat in javascript =), i dont really know how to change my json output for now. Need to get into it more.

Comment: Which technology/language you are using on serverside ?